# Does Chrome support HTTP/3 over a port other than 443?

Tags: google-chrome, http3

I am experimenting with enabling HTTP/3 support on my webserver. In my specific setup, it will not be possible to use UDP port 443, since I have different websites hosted by different webservers on the same public IP address, and I am not aware of any reverse proxy that supports TLS passthrough for HTTP/3.

I have enabled HTTP/3 on port 44113. The service is advertised using the HTTP header `Alt-Svc: h3=":44113"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":44113"; ma=2592000`. Firefox successfully recognizes the service and makes any subsequent requests using HTTP/3. However, Chrome sticks with HTTP/2. When I temporarily moved HTTP/3 to port 443, it suddenly worked in Chrome as well.

Is this behaviour documented anywhere? Are there any cases in which HTTP/3 works over another port than 443 in Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered [on the chromium-discuss mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-discuss/c/GRT5quemqBE), Chromium supports HTTP/3 only on UDP ports < 1024.

The reason can be found [in the source code](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:net/http/http_stream_factory_job_controller.cc;l=1070): Some shared Unix webservers allow individual users to publish their `public_html` directory through HTTP and also to run custom services on ports >= 1024. A malicious user could set an `Alt-Svc` header in their published directory to hijack future HTTP/3 connections to the webserver.